# Peewee insert if not exist

Tags: python, peewee

I am using Python/Mysql and Peewee as ORM. I am stuck in a situation. Suppose i want to insert a row using peewee but check if that row exist skip else insert. Is there any procedure to do so in python using peewee.

Comment: To confirm, you're looking to insert a row if it doesn't exist otherwise don't add it?

Comment: Yes . @Khammel you got it right.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure what you've tried already, but I'd suggest the `Model.get_or_create()` or `Model.create_or_get()` methods from peewee to do what you're looking for:  [Peewee Get or Create](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#create-or-get)

Comment: The `create_or_get` is in master but not in the latest release on PyPI (2.6.1). Expect a new release soon, however.